# facing issue in cython on raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, cython

I am trying to install the tensorflow dependencies .One of the codes is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev cython
```

and i got an error:

```
E: Package 'cython' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 3):

the *cython* package has been updated to *cython3*. And i was able to install it successfully.